# Commerce Licence Renewal Date defaulting to January 1970

Tags: commerce

I'm renewing Licenses in Drupal Commerce and running into a weird issue.

I'm going to mysite.com/admin/commerce/licenses/list

Using the Filter Widget I type the username of the user whose license I'd like to renew. Using the Operations widget, I select Renew Licence and press Execute.

After typing the number of days (for example 1 day) to renew each licence for and pressing Next, the date is defaulting to 2nd January 1970

Ids this a bug or am I missing something in my Commerce set-up. ie: a timezone configuration?

Using D7.34, Commerce 7.x-1.10 and License 7.x-1.3

Comment: January 1970 is unix timestamp equal to 0. In other words, somehow your value is empty. Looks like a bug to me. If you are looking for a ready solution, issue queue would be the best. If you want to hack, try to find out and tell us if value is sent, and at what step it's lost. Oh, and please, link module names to appropriate projects.

Comment: Thanks Molot. Added to an existing issue. https://www.drupal.org/node/2361389